# Should I compress my multiple css files into one for my React js App?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am pretty new to reactjs. Right now my reactjs app is pretty big with many pages and five different CSS files for each big component I am using react-helmet to use CSS for different component.

Do I have to compress css into one file or my method is correct?

I am also rendering both client and server-side with reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

You should start using [webpack + react + css](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2016/07/css-modules-webpack-react/). This is a far better way than using helmet to added different styles based on the page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The link is broken. It says page not found.